# Error when using find/replace method in an embedded Word document in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word, ole

I have an embedded word document in my worksheet, names `"Rec1"`

So using before:

```
Sub ReplaceTextinOLEObject
    Dim oDoc As OLEObject
    Set oDoc = Worksheets("Sheet1").OLEObjects("Rec1")
    oDoc.Activate
    With oDoc.Content.Find
        .ClearFormatting
        .Text = "hi"
        .Replacement.ClearFormatting
        .Replacement.Text = "hello"
        .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll, Forward:=True, Wrap:=wdFindContinue
    End With
    Word.Application.Quit wdDoNotSaveChanges
End Sub
```

When perform running above, the `With` part committed below error:

> Run-time error '438':
>   object doesn't support this property or method

What is the problem of the using `Find` object for OLE embedded word documents?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is that the `OLEObjects` has no `.Content` property. That is also what the error tells you.

Therefore you have to use `oDoc.Object.Content.Find` instead. And you don't need to `oDoc.Activate` the document, it will also work without.

The following should work:

```
Public Sub ReplaceTextinOLEObject
    Dim oDoc As OLEObject
    Set oDoc = Worksheets("Sheet1").OLEObjects("Rec1")
    'oDoc.Activate 'remove this line, activate is not needed here
    With oDoc.Object.Content.Find
        .ClearFormatting
        .Text = "hi"
        .Replacement.ClearFormatting
        .Replacement.Text = "hello"
        .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll, Forward:=True, Wrap:=wdFindContinue
    End With
    Word.Application.Quit wdDoNotSaveChanges
End Sub
```

*Note: Of course the "Microsoft Word 16.0 Object Library" (version may vary) needs to be referenced to run this code.*